# <select> list of hyperlinks: onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" or onchange="location=this.value"

Tags: select, this, onchange

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="myhome.html">My Home Page</option>
<option value="myresume.html">Resume</option>
<option value="myhobbies.html">Hobbies</option>
<option value="mydog.html">My Dog</option>
</select>


<select onchange="location = this.value;">
<option value="myhome.html">My Home Page</option>
<option value="myresume.html">Resume</option>
<option value="myhobbies.html">Hobbies</option>
<option value="mydog.html">My Dog</option>
</select>
```

The first method is taken from http://www.faqs.org/docs/htmltut/forms/_SELECT_onChange.html, but the second method (which I've used) works fine. Is the second method incorrect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think the second method will work fine on most browsers but you need the first method if you're using IE.